# Do I need to restart apache each time after changing code

Tags: django, apache, pycharm

I am deploying a Django app on webfaction. All code are uploaded, but sometimes there are still some modification I need to make. My workflow is edit local file in Pycharm and sync the change to remote server (Apache). So, for example, do I need to restart apache every time after changing views.py for the change to take effects?

Comment: You should not have to. Might I suggest that you not use Apache for python production simply because its too bloated. Use nginx with gunicorn, it is a much better alternative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using modpython yes, you have to reload apache every time or your modules will not be reloaded.

If you are using apache and mod_wsgi then touching the wsgi module is enough.

As other already suggested nginx + gunicorn (or better nginx + uwsgi) are better options than apache + mod_python to serve your django app.

Comment: @TommasoBarugi what is the solution in windows?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you do not have to, you just have to « touch » the wsgi.py file (if you are using the mod_wsgi apache2 module). You can do it by uploading the wsgi.py file every time you upload something.